# Entity Framework One-To-Many Insert - Foreign Key violation

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework for the first time and I'm trying to create a object with a collection (and I want all the objects in the collection to be created in database as well) but I'm having some foreign keys violations.

My sample tables:

```
table APPOINTMENTS: ID, VAR1, DATE_APPOINTMENT
table GUESTS: ID, APPOINTMENT_ID, USER_ID, VAR2, VAR3
```

My test code:

```
DomainService aux = new DomainService();

APPOINTMENTS appointment = new APPOINTMENTS();
appointment.VAR1 = "BLA";
appointment.DATE_APPOINTMENT = new DateTime();

//The user with id = 1 is already created in the database
appointment.GUESTS.Add(new GUESTS { USER_ID = 1, VAR2 = 1, VAR3 = "F" });

aux.InsertAppointment(appointment);
```

At DomainService I have:

```
public void InsertAppointment(APPOINTMENTS appointment)
{
    using (var context = this.ObjectContext)
    {
        context.AddToAPPOINTMENTS(appointment);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:
{"ORA-02291: integrity constraint (FK_GUESTS_APPOINTMENTS) violated - parent key not found"}

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
To create the ID's in the database, I am using a sequence for each table and a trigger before insert to get the next value. 
When I create a single object, e.g. a appointment without guests, it inserts in the database and it generates the id.

Comment: i have done exactly the same thing in EF and it works for me. Primary keys in both tables are auto numbers. I am using sql server for data storage

Comment: I'm using sequences and a trigger before insert... When I try to just create a appointment without guests it generates an ID, and when I try to create a guest with an existing appointmentID it works correctly also

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid He is using Oracle, not SQL Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this problem:

> "The ID fields that are generated from sequences won't be handled
>   correctly. After saving the entities the ID's will be returned as 0.
>   I'll fix this by manually hacking the SSDL (open your .edmx file in a
>   text editor) with StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" attributes on the
>   ID fields (lines 6 and 16). Note that designer may rip that change out
>   upon future modification.
>
> While I suppose it's not absolutely necessary it might also be prudent
>   to modify some type metadata such as changing "number"s to "int"s in
>   your SSDL and "Decimal"s to "Int32"s in your CSDL where applicable.
>   Frequently these don't auto-generate with the desired values
>   especially with XE."

@http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/oracle_entity_framework_ef

Comment: <EntityType Name="Widget">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="WidgetId" />
  </Key>
  <Property Name="WidgetId" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"  Type="number" Nullable="false" Precision="8" />

Answer (score 2):

As for me, the problem was solved simply by opening diagram .edmx and changing property StoreGeneratedPattern from None to Identity for each Primary Key in each table. After saving everything was fine.

I'm using VS 2012, Entity Framework 5 (6 is not supported yet), Oracle 11.2, last ODP.NET 12, .Net 4.5

Answer (score 2):

In case of EF code first approach, if this error come

> (ORA-02291: integrity constraint (FK_GUESTS_APPOINTMENTS) violated -
>   parent key not found)

In my case there are 2 tables which have Identity columns. So I just added

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

property to my model class just above the the column which is identity column in database and it solved my problem :)

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

I cant see where you are setting your Primary Key (the ID property of the appointment class). Are you using a key generator on the database side? If not this should be the problem.

Comment: I'm using a sequence and a trigger getting the next value before insert.

Answer (score -1):

You're inserting a record with a foreign key value that is not found in the parent table that constraint refers back to.

Comment: Well, isn't supose the Entity Framework to Insert the Appointment and the Guest with the currect APPOINTMENT_ID FK?

Comment: I'm not a java programmer, so I have no idea what your entity framework does or does not do.  If the framework is supposed to insert the parent first, is it possible you have more setup to do for your object?  Looking at your code, if I'm reading it right you are creating the GUEST before the APPOINTMENT, with GUEST.APPOINTMENT_ID being the foreign key back to APPOINTMENT.APPOINTMENT_ID.  When creating the GUEST object do you have a record in the APPOINTMENT table with APPOINTMENT_ID=1?

Comment: Found out the problem. It was a mapping problem... You need to make a few alterations to the generated mapping to be able to do this. EF doesn't like Oracle xD