# How can I update related tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

My project involves creating a new hotel room and 2 tables in my database will update. My tables are called RoomType and RoomFacility.

I can successfully update RoomType, but when I try to update RoomFacility and use RoomTypeID to make a new room facility, it fails. I always get 1 for my RoomFacilityID.

How can I update data for both tables, roomType and RoomFacility?

This is the code for my service to update my database

```
 public void UpdateFacilityInRooms(List<int> FacilityIDs, int RoomTypeID)
    {
        List<HotelRoomFacility> hotelRoomFacilities =
                            _HotelRoomFacilityRopository.AsQueryable()
                            .Where(f => f.RoomTypeID == RoomTypeID).ToList();

        foreach (int newRoomFacility in FacilityIDs)
        {
            if (hotelRoomFacilities.Where(h => h.RoomFacilityID == newRoomFacility).Count() == 0)
            {
                HotelRoomFacility facility = new HotelRoomFacility
                {
                    RoomFacilityID = newRoomFacility,
                    RoomTypeID = RoomTypeID
                };
                _HotelRoomFacilityRopository.Add(facility);
            }
        }
        _HotelRoomFacilityRopository.CommitChanges();
    }




 public RoomType NewRoom(int HotelID,int? RoomTypeID, 
                        string RoomTypeName, string RoomTypeDescription)
    {
        RoomType room = new RoomType();
        room.HotelID = HotelID;
        room.RoomTypeID = RoomTypeID ?? 0;
        room.RoomtypeName = RoomTypeName;
        room.RoomTypeDescripton = RoomTypeDescription;

        _RoomTypeRepository.Add(room);

        _RoomTypeRepository.CommitChanges();

        return room;
      }
```

Comment: You are using Entity Framework, yes?

Comment: Then I think this question will help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/7609721/1411687 or maybe this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/13973836/1411687

Comment: check FacilityIDs. Does it contain more than one element?

Comment: can you give me some example?

Comment: One comment, you may want to consider replacing "hotelRoomFacilities.Where(h => h.RoomFacilityID == newRoomFacility).Count() == 0" with "!hotelRoomFacilities.Any(h => h.RoomFacilityID == newRoomFacility)" or "hotelRoomFacilities.All(h => h.RoomFacilityID != newRoomFacility)" for readability. The actual Count is unimportant. And, if you invert the comparison, you could use Any() to avoid having to enumerate them all the facilities.

Comment: This code is pretty confusing. First, is RoomFacilityID the PK on HotelRoomFacility? Can you include the code defining this model? Second, since your repo code isn't included here, the bug could be in the repo code itself, or an adverse interaction with it.

Comment: thanks for all comment for me. my problem is solve. thanks

Comment: It would be nice novan if you wrote the solution to your issue

Comment: oke pater, thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public RoomType UpdateRoom(int RoomTypeID, string RoomTypeName, string RoomTypeDescription, List<int> RoomFacilityIDs)
        {

            RoomType roomType = (from rt in _RoomTypeRepository.AsQueryable().Include(r => r.HotelRoomFacilities)
                                 where rt.RoomTypeID == RoomTypeID
                                select rt).FirstOrDefault();

            if (roomType == null)
                return null;

            roomType.RoomTypeName = RoomTypeName;
            roomType.RoomTypeDescripton = RoomTypeDescription;

            //Add New Room facilities
            List<HotelRoomFacility> hotelRoomFacilities = _HotelRoomFacilityRopository.AsQueryable().Where(f => f.RoomTypeID == RoomTypeID).ToList();
            foreach (int newRoomFacilityID in RoomFacilityIDs)
            {
                if (roomType.HotelRoomFacilities.Where(h => h.RoomFacilityID == newRoomFacilityID).Count() == 0)
                {
                    roomType.HotelRoomFacilities.Add(new HotelRoomFacility
                    {
                        RoomFacilityID = newRoomFacilityID
                    });
                }
            }


            foreach (HotelRoomFacility roomFacility in hotelRoomFacilities)
            {
                if (RoomFacilityIDs.Contains(roomFacility.RoomFacilityID) == false)
                    _HotelRoomFacilityRopository.Delete(roomFacility);
            }

            _RoomTypeRepository.Attach(roomType);
            _RoomTypeRepository.CommitChanges();

            return roomType;
        }
```